# Python - Reading Config

Tags: python, python-3.x, config

I have been doing a lot of Python code testing recently and have been loading many items from a config.ini file using the configparser.

Currently I have a function that does this:

```
def get_config(config_sector=None, config_key=None):

    config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read("..\config\config.ini")

    return config[config_sector][config_key]
```

Calling the function:

```
image_output_directory = get_config("SCREENSHOT", "ImageDir")
image_filename_format = get_config("SCREENSHOT", "NameFmt")
datetime_format = get_config("SCREENSHOT", "NameDTFmt")
ff_options_config = get_config("SCREENSHOT", "Options")
...
```

Is it possible to do the same in a more efficient manner?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you read the config file every time you run the function instead of just reading it once?

Comment: Actually now that you mentioned it, I have realised it. I did not even hit my head for once that I kept reading the config over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read it once then reuse the same object, instead of creating it again and again.

```
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read("..\config\config.ini")

image_output_directory = config["SCREENSHOT"]["ImageDir"]
image_filename_format = config["SCREENSHOT"]["NameFmt"]
...
```

Comment: Is it possible to put this in a separate python file such as a config.py then import that and use all the variables from that "custom module"?

Comment: You could potentially do that. If you did, I would make a class that on `__init__` ran the config parser and populated instance attributes with the variables you defined in your question. That way, you wouldn't have to worry about getting errors trying to read the config file at import time.

Comment: If you want to do that, then the question is where would the config variable go. If you really want to achieve that, then I can think of two solutions,

1. Instead of a module, use a class. A class can have the config as an instance variable and a single line function that takes a config_sector and a config_key and returns config[config_sector][config_key]
2. A module function to return the config object that loads it and module functions that take the loaded config object, key and sector.

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate the help. I think the __init__ with the class sounds good. Cheers! @SanilKhurana thanks for the additional info as well!